# When sending email with Postfix, how can I hide the sender’s IP and username in the Received header?

Tags: postfix

When sending mail, *Postfix* inserts the authenticated user’s IP and username into the Received header on the email. While this is useful for tracking down who sent a particular email that was sent from your mail server, it also has privacy implications. In a small-scale situation where I can trust all the users not to get their accounts compromised and turned into spam zombies, I’d rather not broadcast IP addresses and account names for all to read. In short, how do I set up *Postfix* to not send this:

> Received: from [x.x.x.x] (pc1.example.com  [x.x.x.x]) (using TLSv1
>   with cipher DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA (256/256 bits))    (No client certificate
>   requested)    (Authenticated sender: user)    by  mail.example.com
>   (Postfix) with ESMTPSA id CC77010C148 for  ; Fri, 11
>   Nov 2011 04:55:18 +0000 (UTC)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The standard solution is to use the [header_checks](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#header_checks) option. This *will* work, however, if we filter received lines on all mail both incoming and outgoing (as this will do), we could potentially lose Received headers on mail sent *to* us, which can be important for troubleshooting. To get around this problem, we will apply the `header_checks` only to the mail that could not possibly have been sent to us—mail that was sent to the *submission* port (you *are* using the [submission port](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Postfix#Using_Port_587_for_Secure_Submission), *aren’t you?*).

What we need to do is pass the [cleanup_service_name](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#cleanup_service_name) option to the *submission* service so that we can set up a new cleanup service, “subcleanup.” The relevant section of `/etc/postfix/master.cf` might look like this:

```
submission inet n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
  -o cleanup_service_name=subcleanup
```

Now we can pass the `header_checks` option to the new cleanup service. That part of `/etc/postfix/master.cf` might look like this:

```
cleanup   unix  n       -       -       -       0       cleanup
subcleanup unix n       -       -       -       0       cleanup
  -o header_checks=regexp:/etc/postfix/submission_header_checks
```

Finally, we need to create the file `/etc/postfix/submission_header_checks`, which will contain the regex that filters offending Received header lines.  Which regex you put in the file depends on whether you have `smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header` set.

If `smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header` is `yes`, then use:

```
/^Received:.*\(Authenticated sender:/ IGNORE
```

Otherwise, use:

```
/^Received:.*\(Postfix/ IGNORE
```

(Thanks to Dominic P and Bryan Drewery for showing how to handle the second case.)

Comment: Do you have to call `postmap submission_header_checks`?

Comment: @Mitar no clue, but if you find out that you do, feel free to edit the answer. These are old instructions for 10.04, but I'll probably be updating them when 14.04 comes out.

Comment: It seems it worked without. :-)

Comment: +1, thanks for the very helpful answer. It's a few years later, and I had to make a minor tweak. I'm running Postfix 2.9.6. I changed the regex to: `/^Received:.*\(Postfix/ IGNORE` because I wasn't getting the "Authenticated sender" portion in my headers. Do you see any risks associated with my new regex?

Comment: This answer assumes smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header=yes is set. Without it then the modified regex by Dominic is needed.

Comment: Please note that with `smtpd_proxy_filter` the `cleanup` will be skipped.  The same applies to `receive_override_options=no_header_body_checks`. The latter is more obvious, but still.

Comment: Why can't you just match on `^Received:`? In the submission queue there should only be one (the unwanted) Received header, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Solving the problem of two "Received" headers from PHPLIST.

We open `/etc/postfix/main.cf`. Add at the end:

```
header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks
```

Сreate the file `/etc/postfix/header_checks`. We write in it:

```
/^Received:/ IGNORE
```

Finally, reload postfix

Comment: It was indeed this simple for me, thanks! Other guides tell you to change `master.cf` as well when this is all you need, at least if you want to filter *all* emails. I did run into errors after modifying `main.cf` first and then was creating `header_checks`, where postfix somehow picked up the config change and started throwing errors for emails currently being sent because `header_checks` didn't exist yet. Then, when it did exist, it didn't pick that up. A restart is definitely advisable after finalizing the changes, and perhaps create the `header_checks` file before modifying `main.cf`.

Answer (score -3):

You can use

```
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = no
```

in `postfix/main.cf` to eliminate the header information in your outgoing mails.

Comment: why is this answer much simpler than @Michael's? does this remove the IP from all headers, instead of just from the mails received through the submission port?

Comment: @knocte [`smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header) is set to "no" by default anyway. When it is enabled, Postfix adds the username that was used for SASL authentication to the initial "Received" header — that's what adds the "Authenticated sender: user" part shown in the question. @Michael's answer removes not only the user part, but the entire "Received" header, including the client's IP.

Comment: @n.st: are you saying that Markus' answer doesn't remove the IP and therefore doesn't this S.O. question?

Comment: @knocte Exactly.

Comment: alright and why don't we downvote him then?

Comment: I need 125+ to downvote.
I've tested it and it removes the Username only, not the IP.